# Problem reading foreign characters Winform Textbox from database

Tags: sql, winforms

please help. in Visual Studio 2017 and SQL `localDB` - WinForm learns and makes a small application. Form (Textbox), where "name, surname, address, city, phone and email" is written in Czech language containing "ěščřžýáíé" ". Everything is stored in the database (`nvarchar`) in order. Everything OK.

In Form2 I have another form where Combobox calls a "surname" and it has to fill in the phone and e-mail automatically from the database. If the surname is without the character "ěščřžýáíé", everything will be displayed correctly. If it contains "ěščřžýáíé", only the last name will be displayed, but the phone and email will not be loaded into the TextBox.

The code sample (without ěščřžýáíé) works perfectly:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\newtest.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        string sql = "select * from test111 WHERE firmadat ='" + prijmeniComboBox.Text + "'; ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader myreader;

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myreader.Read())
            {
                string rollno = myreader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                string name = myreader.GetString(1);
                string telephone = myreader.GetString(3);
                string email = myreader.GetString(4);
                textBox1.Text = rollno;


                telefonTextBox.Text = telephone;
                emailTextBox.Text = email;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you all who tried to help. I tried the code below and works great!             
                                                                                                                            
 string sql = "select * from xxxtxxx WHERE xxxdat like N'%" + firmaComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + "%'";

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably here:

```
string sql = "select * from test111 WHERE firmadat ='" + prijmeniComboBox.Text + "'; ";
```

Here you take your Unicode string and you concatenate it into a SQL string that is not a Unicode string. I would tell you how to get it working as you intended but **this is a really really dangerous way to write SQLs**. [Someone at kids' toy maker VTech wrote SQLs this way](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vtech+sql+injection) and enabled a hacker to download millions of images of children taken by vtech devices. If one of my developers wrote SQL like this they would be subject to disciplinary action, possibly being fired.

I strongly recommend that you use parameterized SQLs; any number of internet resources will show you how, such as http://bobby-tables.com - it will also solve the problem of getting no results when searching using a search term that contains non-ASCII characters

Take a look at http://dapper-tutorial.net ; using dapper will not only take care of the parameterizing for you, but make your database life easier by reducing your code to just a couple of lines, something like:

```
using(SqlCommand x = new SqlCommand(conn)
{
  var p = x.Query(
    "select * from test111 WHERE firmadat = @a",
    new { a = prijmeniComboBox.Text }
  );

  firstNameTextBox.Text = p.FirstName; //or what the column is called on db
  ...
}
```

You just write your sql, use @namedParameter placeholders and supply an anonymous object with properties named after the placeholders. Dapper does the rest. If you have a Person class in your project you can even get dapper to create it and populate it for you